# why laravel fractal Transformer create lots of Queries when i pass get() method queries result to it?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eager-loading

hi friends i am using the package "spatie/laravel-fractal".

Actually i am not able to understand if this is a problem or just the way fractal works, but when i include a fractal transformer in another i get a new query for each result of the first transformer. In other words, if i list "Shifts" and in with() method i pass "Jobs", for each "Shift" i will have a query to get the jobs.

**ShiftController (method here)**

```
public function list(Request $request)
{

    $shiftData = Shift::with(['job'])
            ->withCount('job_applications')->active()
             ->orderBy('start_date_time', 'asc')->get();

    $resource = new Collection($shiftData, new ShiftTransformer());

    $array = $this->fractal->createData($resource)->toArray();

    $array['count'] = count($array['data']);

    return $this->respondWithCode($array, Illuminate::HTTP_OK);
}
```

**ShiftTransformer**

```
class ShiftTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    protected $availableIncludes = [
       'roles', 'notifications', 'permissions'
     ];

   public function transform(shift $shift)
   {
      $job_sub_title = is_null($shift->job_sub_title) ? $shift->job->title : $shift->job->title . ' - ' . $shift->job_sub_title;

      return [
          'id' => (string)$shift->id,
          'title' => $job_sub_title,
      ];
   }

  }
```

**Relation of Shift Table with Job Table**

**Shift Model**

```
public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job', 'job_shift', 'shift_id', 'job_id');
    }
```

**Job Model**

```
public function shifts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Shift', 'job_shift');
    }
```

**Multiple Queries**

why i am getting lots of queries as such as below because in Transformer class i am not executing any query

select `shifts`.*, (select count(*) from `job_applications` where `shifts`.`id` = `job_applications`.`shift_id` and `job_applications`.`deleted_at` is null) as `job_applications_count` from `shifts` where exists (select * from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `shifts`.`id` = `job_shift`.`shift_id` and `is_active` = 1 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null) and exists (select * from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `shifts`.`id` = `job_shift`.`shift_id` and exists (select * from `clients` where `jobs`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` and `id` in (6, 3) and `clients`.`deleted_at` is null) and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null) and max_staffs != approved_staffs and `shifts`.`deleted_at` is null order by `start_date_time` asc [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` in (6, 7, 8, 9, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 64, 247, 251, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 263, 264, 266, 267, 354, 369, 380, 381, 382, 383, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 466, 468, 474, 479, 536, 540) and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 64 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 31 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 32 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 35 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 57 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 53 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 34 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 56 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 54 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 55 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 33 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 52 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 251 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 266 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 264 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 267 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 257 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 258 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 255 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 256 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 263 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 259 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 354 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 382 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 383 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 380 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 369 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 455 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 456 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 51 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 247 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 381 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 466 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 468 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 479 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 474 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 26 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 30 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 29 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 9 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 454 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 457 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 453 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 536 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 540 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 7 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 6 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

select `jobs`.*, `job_shift`.`shift_id` as `pivot_shift_id`, `job_shift`.`job_id` as `pivot_job_id` from `jobs` inner join `job_shift` on `jobs`.`id` = `job_shift`.`job_id` where `job_shift`.`shift_id` = 8 and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 [] []

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. The following link might help you solve the issue in a better way using the Laravel collection helper.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 0):

This is not might be proper solution but try to add
Model::preventlazyloading() in boot function of AppServiceProvider